# Closed variable anulled in Rx callback

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2

My understanding is that in the following code variable `context` should never be null.

But, when debugger is attached, variable context is frequently null when lambda is executed.

This behavior is reproducible three out of five times.

How can that be explained?

```
object MyOtherService {
  private val TAG = "MyOtherService"

  fun start(context:Context){
    context.getString(android.R.string.ok) // no exception

    Log.d(TAG, "context ok")

    SlowServiceObserver
      .getObservable()
      .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
      .subscribe({
        context.getString(android.R.string.ok) // null reference exception thrown sometimes
      })
  }
}

public class MyApp extends Application {

  public void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();

    MyService.INSTANCE.start(this);

    SlowService slowService = new SlowService();
    SlowServiceObserver.INSTANCE.notify(slowService);
  }    
}

object SlowServiceObserver {

  private val mBehaviorSubject : BehaviorSubject<BehaviorSubject> = BehaviorSubject.create()

  fun getObservable(){
    return mBehaviorSubject
  }

  fun notify(instance: SlowService){
     mBehaviorSubject.onNext(instance)
  }
}
```

Can it be that Kotlin `object` somehow changes the closure? Or is this some expected behavior in RxJava?

**Edit**

Attempted workarounds:

- introduce private property with context and use that in subscribe callback - works - no exception
- assign disposable to private property - does not help
- change kotlin object to class and invoke from application - new exception (only with debugger attached):

stack trace

```
art/runtime/runtime.cc:286] Pending exception java.lang.NullPointerException thrown by 'void MyOtherService.start(android.content.Context):39'
art/runtime/runtime.cc:286] java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'java.lang.String MyOtherService.TAG' on a null object reference
art/runtime/runtime.cc:286]   at void MyOtherService.start(android.content.Context) (MyOtherService.kt:39)
art/runtime/runtime.cc:286]   at void MyApplication.onCreate() (MyApplication.java:106)
art/runtime/runtime.cc:286]   at void android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(android.app.Application) (Instrumentation.java:1026)
```

akarnokd has proposed that this is a bug in (kotlin?) compiler. 
Or maybe it's a bug in Android Studio?

**Edit 2**

Per comment, I've tried to make a contained sample and checked out another working copy. `context` was not null no matter how many times I tried to reproduce the issue. I guess the issue must be related to some intermediate build artifacts.
Clean/Rebuild Project and Invalidate caches didn't help though.

Comment: You can't rely on the context in the `start` function. You're working on the computation thread. The context is scoped to the start function, but you're trying to use it asynchronously in another thread, where the start function has already left. You should keep a weak reference to your context in your `MyOtherService` class and set it in your `start` function. Afterwards you can safely access it.

Comment: If it was plain Java, `context` should be consistent with the two logs. However, if there is a chance `start()` can be called with null, you may not properly match up the two `log` printouts.

Comment: @akarnokd `start()` is called once 
@DenisLoh can you point to some reference documentation or blog post which further explains this?

Comment: In that case, you have either found a compiler bug, you have the `!=` operator overridden for `Context` types or you didn't show the actual code that gives the problem. For example, I've seen cases when the user calls `println(someObj)` and sees `null`, but `someObj != null`. This happens because `someObj` is an empty reference container thus `someObj.toString()` prints its content as null.

Comment: @akarnokd it's really null. I've modified the sample to better reflect that

Comment: Assign the `Disposable` returned by the `subscribe()` method to a field and see if that helps.

Comment: @akarnokd tried it - it did not make a difference

Comment: Then its not a GC issue. Could you post a minimalist but full project on GitHub that demonstrates the problem?